# How do I go about finding an equivalent MOSFET when I can't find one with the original part number?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification

I am trying to find a part for my Mecer inverter. It is a MOSFET part number STP11N45NFP.  I cannot find it and do not know how to find an equivalent.

Comment: It is very difficult to find an equivalent without an accurate datasheet. Suggest you post a sharp close-up photo of the part in question. We may be able to see something that is not obvious to you.

Comment: It is difficult to choose an alternative part as *some* parameters will have been key to the selection of the original part. The issue is that we don't know *which* parameters were the important ones.

Comment: It might be similar to this one: [PTP11N45](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2006111813_PIP-PTA11N45_C575808.pdf)